# Custom ListView adapter. TextChangedListener calls for wrong EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, adapter

I have the list of travelers with custom adapter what consist two EditText - edtFirstName and edtLastName. I want when user enters text save changes to List, and when next button click send this List to another activity.

My code:

```
public class TravellersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private List<Traveler> itemsList;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  private Activity context;

  public TravellersAdapter(Activity context, List<Traveler> itemsList) {
    super();
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  public int getCount() { return itemsList.size();  }

  public Object getItem(int i) {  return itemsList.get(i);  }

  public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.traveller_item, null);
    }
    Traveler currentItem = (Traveler) getItem(position);

    EditText firstNameView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtFirstName);
    firstNameView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        currentItem.setFirstName(editable.toString());
      }

    });

    return view;
  }
}
```

For exemple List itemsList consist 5 items. When I edit 2-4 element all ok, but when I edit first or last element edited value assigned to all element in List. In dubugger i saw that method `afterTextChanged` calls 5 times with different values of `position`. 
How to fix it?

Comment: your firstNameView is recycled for several items. Your currentItem as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in **getView** method, the parameter **position** gives the position of the newly created **childView**, not the clicked childView's position.

use this to get the correct position:

```
final int actual_position = myList.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
```

in `onClick(View v);` of the `onClickListener` of any View. In you case, you must implement **onTextChangedListener** for that EditText.

*here:*

**myList** is the ListView

**v** is the View you clicked, in this case the childView of the parent(myList).

Answer (score 2):

The issue happens because views are reusable (that is by design in Android API). So eventually you may assign more than 1 text watcher to the same text view. And all of the assigned watchers are fired when text inside of the text view is changed.

A quick fix (and non-optimal if the list is really long, say, of 1000+ items) would be to have a map of `Traweller -> TextWatcher`.

Then inside of getView() you can do this (pseudo-code):

- check the map if there is a `TextWatcher` for this `Traweller`
- if map does not have any, then create a new `TextWatcher`, put in the map and assign to `EditText`
- otherwise detach the `TextWatcher` from the `EditText` and remove from the map
- create a new `TextWatcher`, put in the map and assign to `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

Create one more `EditText` in the screen that is invisible with name `invivisbleEt`.
And do the following thing in the `addTextChangedListener`

```
firstNameView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if(!firstNameView.isFocused())
            currentItem.setFirstName(editable.toString());
    }

});
```

Also add this code in the `onCreate` method for `ListView` object.

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

    //public boolean scrolling;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
        invivisbleEt.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
});
```