# How to get the value of a EditText, which is set by a custom listview adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

i have a listview adapter. there is a list which is a EditText. i have a button. now when the button is clicked, i want to get the value of the edittext.
N.B: two list in the adapter. EditText's position is 1 and another list's position is 0.

in onCreate():

```
    private ListView listView;
private List<BaseListElement> listElements;

    listElements = new ArrayList<BaseListElement>();
    listElements.add(new FriendList(0));
    listElements.add(new TextArea(1));

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore the state for each list element
        for (BaseListElement listElement : listElements) {
            listElement.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }   
    }

    // Set the list view adapter
    listView.setAdapter(new ActionListAdapter(getActivity(), 
                        R.id.list, listElements));

    shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);
    Svalue = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Tstatus);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String value = Svalue.getText().toString();

            if(value != null && value.length()>0){
                Log.e("msg", value);
            }
```

adapter:

```
    private class ActionListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BaseListElement> {
    private final String Tag = "ActionAdapter";
    int k = 0;
    private List<BaseListElement> listElements;

    public ActionListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<BaseListElement> listElements) {
        super(context, resourceId, listElements);
        this.listElements = listElements;
        for (int i = 0; i < listElements.size(); i++) {
            listElements.get(i).setAdapter(this);
        }
        k = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            if(position == 0){
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shareview, null);
            }else{
                LayoutInflater inflater =
                        (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textarea, null);
            }
            k = k++;
            String ki = Integer.toString(position);
            Log.e(Tag, ki);

        }
        else{
            String ki = Integer.toString(position);
            Log.e(Tag, "else : "+ki);
        }

        BaseListElement listElement = listElements.get(position);

            view.setOnClickListener(listElement.getOnClickListener());
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.withWhom);
            TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectFriend);
            EditText status = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Tstatus);
            if (icon != null && position == 0) {
                icon.setImageDrawable(listElement.getIcon());
            }
            if (text1 != null && position == 0) {
                text1.setText(listElement.getWithWhom());
            }
            if (text2 != null && position == 0) {
                text2.setText(listElement.getSelectFriend());
            }
            if(status != null)
            Log.e("adapter class", status.getText().toString());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for my question. i find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670737/custom-listview-adapter-textchangedlistener-calls-for-wrong-edittext)

if the `position` is my desire list's position, then in the `if()` scope
i use `textchangelistener()` to get the value.

for my circumstance, the position of my desire list is always 1. so i use `textchangelistener()` under `if(position == 1)` scope.