# In addTextChangedListener inside the listview Using Custom List Adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am developing an appliction for invoice creation.for which user have to adding a list of items and set the quanity.the datas are added in a listview.for which i used an custom list adapter which extends a base adapter.for the first item if user select the qty as 15(for eg)for a item.qty as shows 15 until next item is added.if another one is added then the previously setted qty change to current one.I am using addTextChangedListener inside Custom List Adapter.when i change qty using addTextChangedListener all rows affected.I am using a Custom Adapter to fill a listview. Each row in a listview has 3 textviews(Custom Layout), and an edittext for entering the quantity.Another Problem is when scrolled the ListView the value repeats/change automatically in the edit text.why?
[image]

[image]

Here is my main class,

```
public class SalesTransactionFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    Button b1,b2,b3;
    TextView tvcusid,tvcusname,tvtotal;
    ListView lv;
    public static itemlistadapter itadapter;
    static ArrayList<Items>  item ;
    Items it;

    String cus_id,c_name;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab3.xml
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.salesform, container, false);
          return view;

    }

   @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    b1=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sfbtncus);
    b2=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sfbtnadd);
    b3=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sfbtfinish);
    itadapter=null;
  it=new Items();
    tvcusid=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sftvcusid);
    tvcusname=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sftvcusname);
    tvtotal=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sftotal);
    lv=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sflvitem);
    lv.setTranscriptMode(lv.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    item = new ArrayList<Items>();

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CustomerSelect.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);   
//          Intent i = new Intent(SalesFormActivity.this, CustomerSelect.class);
//          i.putExtra("cussel", "true");
//          startActivityForResult(i, 0);   
        //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CustomerSelect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//          
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ItemsView.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);           
//          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "AddItem",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Finish",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             if(itadapter==null)
                {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Must select a item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
         else if(cus_id!=null&&itadapter!=null){
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(), Invoice.class);
            i.putExtra("cus_id", cus_id);

                i.putExtra("c_name", c_name);

                startActivity(i);
//                getActivity().finish();

            }
            else if (cus_id==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Must select a customer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }




        }
    });
}
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(data!=null)
    switch (requestCode) {
//      case 0:
//          cus_id=data.getStringExtra("cus_id");
//          c_name=data.getStringExtra("c_name");
//          tvcusid.setText(cus_id);
//          tvcusname.setText(c_name);
//          
//          break;
    case 0:
        it=new Items();
        it.setitemname(data.getStringExtra("name"));
        it.setprice(data.getDoubleExtra("price",0));
        it.setid(data.getIntExtra("item_id", 0));
        if(itadapter==null){
            item.add(it);
            itadapter=new itemlistadapter(item, getActivity());
            lv.setAdapter(itadapter);
            lv.setSelection(itadapter.getCount()-1);

        }else{

            itadapter.addItems(it);
        }
        if(itadapter!=null){
            tvtotal.setText(""+itadapter.gettotal());
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        cus_id=data.getStringExtra("cusid");
        c_name=data.getStringExtra("cusname");
        tvcusid.setText(cus_id);
        tvcusname.setText(c_name);

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }


   }
   @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

Here is the adapter class,

```
public class itemlistadapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    ArrayList<Items> item;
    ArrayList<Items> history;
    HashMap<Integer, Double> prices;
    Context con;
    double grantTotal = 0;

    public itemlistadapter(ArrayList<Items> item, Context con) {
        super();
        this.item = item;
        this.con = con;
        history = (ArrayList<Items>) item.clone();
        prices = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater lvinflat = (LayoutInflater) con
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = lvinflat.inflate(R.layout.singlesalelist, parent,
                    false);
        }
        final int pos = position;
        final TextView tvitem = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sinlvtvname);
        final TextView price = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sinlvtvprice);

        final EditText qty = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sinlvetqty);
        if (pos == item.size() - 1) {
            // Log.d("focusposition",
            // ""+pos+"qty.requestFocus()"+qty.requestFocus());
            qty.requestFocus();
        }
        final TextView tvtotal = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sinlvtvtotal);
        tvitem.setText(item.get(position).getitemname());

        price.setText("" + item.get(position).getprice());

        qty.setText("" + item.get(pos).getqty());
        Log.d("position", "" + pos + "qty" + item.get(position).getqty());

//      if (qty.length() != 0) {
//          int qnty = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());
//      //  item.get(pos).setqty(qnty);
//      //  Log.d("positionqty.length() != 0:", ""+pos+"qty"+item.get(position).getqty());
//
//          double unitp = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());
//          double total = (qnty * unitp);
//          tvtotal.setText("" + total);
//          prices.put(pos, total);
//      } else {
//
//          tvtotal.setText("" + 0);
//      }
        qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                Log.d("On text changed", s+",Start:"+start+",count:"+count+",before:"+before);
                if (s.length() != 0) {
                    int qnty = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                    item.get(pos).setqty(qnty);
                    Log.d("position in ChangedListener", ""+pos+"qty"+item.get(pos).getqty()+"qnty"+qnty);

                    double unitp = Double.parseDouble(price.getText()
                            .toString());
                    double total = (qnty * unitp);
                    tvtotal.setText("" + total);
                    prices.put(pos, total);
                } else {

                    tvtotal.setText("" + 0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                Log.d("Before text changed", s+",Start:"+start+",count:"+count+",after:"+after);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                Log.d("After text changed", s+"");
            }
        });

        if (tvtotal.getText().equals("total")||tvtotal.getText().equals("Total"))
            tvtotal.setText(price.getText());
        try{
        prices.put(pos, Double.parseDouble(tvtotal.getText().toString()));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            //TODO
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public void addItems(Items i) {
        item.add(i);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ArrayList<Items> getItems() {
        return item;
    }

    public double gettotal() {
        grantTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < prices.size(); i++) {
            grantTotal += prices.get(i);
        }
        return grantTotal;
    }

    Filter my_filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            item = (ArrayList<Items>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.d("insitefilterresults", "msg");
            FilterResults filter_results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Items> arr = new ArrayList<Items>();
            if (constraint != null && history != null) {
                for (Items s : history) {
                    if (s.getitemname().startsWith(constraint.toString()))
                        arr.add(s);
                }
                filter_results.values = arr;
                filter_results.count = arr.size();
            }
            return filter_results;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Log.d("insitegetFilte", "msg");

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return my_filter;
    }

}
```

LogCat is,

```
03-27 05:18:57.692: D/Before text changed(409): 1,Start:1,count:0,after:1
03-27 05:18:57.692: D/Before text changed(409): 1,Start:1,count:0,after:1
03-27 05:18:57.702: D/On text changed(409): 15,Start:1,count:1,before:0
03-27 05:18:57.702: D/position in ChangedListener(409): 0qty15qnty15
03-27 05:18:57.722: D/On text changed(409): 15,Start:1,count:1,before:0
03-27 05:18:57.732: D/position in ChangedListener(409): 1qty15qnty15
03-27 05:18:57.742: D/After text changed(409): 15
03-27 05:18:57.742: D/After text changed(409): 15
```

Please help me solve This. Help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: The value in qty changes when scrolled the listview

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a problem I think You have the Array list for the all the data so When you are calculating something in your Text Watcher So at that time you have to 
**update the arraylist data into your new one calculated data You just use the put function for updation beacause you know the position value**
that's all every time you update when you changing the value That's enough

Answer (score 0):

Inside `qty.addTextChangedListener` after `prices.put(pos, total);`

add this piece of code.

`((BaseAdapter) lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: lv is not accessible in the adapter class

Comment: @Noufal change `ListView lv;` to `public ListView lv;`

Comment: when i as per you said.after adding three items when i try to change the qty in 3rd pos..at the same time qty of first place change simultaniously to the third entry

Answer (score 0):

in getView method, the parameter position gives the position of the newly created childView, not the clicked childView's position

So, you need to get the Correct Position Numeber..

Check this link for complete detail, [Custom ListView adapter. TextChangedListener calls for wrong EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670737/custom-listview-adapter-textchangedlistener-calls-for-wrong-edittext)

One more helpful Post is [Android - EditTexts within ListView bound to Custom ArrayAdapter - keeping track of changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735936/android-edittexts-within-listview-bound-to-custom-arrayadapter-keeping-track)